# SpockFramework Global Mocks not working as expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm using the following test as an example to showcase a similar issue I'm seeing. I think it's just a misunderstanding on my part about how global mocks work in SpockFramework.

```
  void "test"() {
    when:
    TestStage stage = new TestStage("John")
    GroovyMock(TestStep.class, global: true) {
      getName() >> "Joe"
    }
    then:
    stage.run() == "Joe"
  }
```

This test should create a test stage supplying a default name. But then I create a global mock of a class inside of `TestStage` to override the return value. IE: I'm only trying to test the functionality of `TestStage` not `TestStep`. If `TestStep` were to make only changes, I don't want to know about them, I'll test those separately. However when I run this test, it looks like the global mock never takes effect as the returned name is still `"John"`, which is what I supplied originally.

```
stage.run() == "Joe"
|     |     |
|     John  false
```

Here's the two sample classes used to test this.

```
class TestStage {
  TestStep step

  TestStage(String name) {
    this.step = new TestStep(name)
  }

  String run() {
    return step.getName()
  }

}
```

```
class TestStep {
    private String name

    TestStep(String name) {
      this.name = name
    }

    String getName() {
      return this.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why `GroovyMock` not spock `Mock`?

Comment: A regular `Mock` cannot be global, or at least that's an error I get when I try to set it as one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you are asking a good question here. According to the Spock manual, it seems as if you could use `GroovyMock` and `GroovyStub` in order to globally replace instances and stub their methods as you tried to do, even though if I were you I would have created the global mock object first before implicitly using it in the constructor of the object depending on it. But anyway, it does not work as expected, like you said.

When I searched the Spock manual and the Spock source code for examples concerning `GroovyMock`, nowhere did I find a single one involving anything else than static methods. The test coverage there is quite bad, actually. Usually, if the manual does not help me, I look if I can infer from the tests how to use a feature. In this case, I had to try by myself.

The first thing I noticed is the completely counter-intuitive fact that **when calling a constructor on a global `GroovyMock` or `GroovyStub`, it returns `null`!!!** This is a real caveat. In a way, constructors are treated like normal mock methods here, also returning `null`. Nowhere does any official source mention that, and I also think it should be changed to default to returning a normal Spock mock instead (if the class is mockable, i.e. non-final).

Now this is also the key to the **solution: You need to stub one or more constructors to return something else than `null`,** e.g. a previously created normal instance or a Spock mock/stub/spy.

Here is a slightly altered version of your source code. I renamed the application classes so as not to contain `Test` in their names. All those `Test` class names were a little confusing to me, especially because I also named my Spock specification `*Test`, as I usually do instead of `*Spec`, because then Maven Surefire/Failsafe can detect it automatically without extra configuration.

I also added a static method to the class to be mocked in order to show you the syntax for stubbing that, too. That is just a free add-on and not directly related to your question.

My test shows three variants:

- using a classical Spock mock and injecting it into the subject under test
- using a global `GroovySpy`, which is always based on a real object (or instructed to create one). Therefore, you do not need to stub a contructor.
- using a global `GroovyMock` with an explicitly stubbed constructor. In my example it returns a regular Spock mock with a stubbed method, but it could also return a normal instance.

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61667088

class Step {
  private String name

  Step(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  String getName() {
    return this.name
  }

  static String staticMethod() {
    return "original"
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61667088

class Stage {
  Step step

  Stage(String name) {
    this.step = new Step(name)
  }

  String run() {
    return step.getName()
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q61667088

import spock.lang.Specification

class GlobalMockTest extends Specification {

  def "use Spock mock"() {
    given:
    def step = Mock(Step) {
      getName() >> "Joe"
    }
    def stage = new Stage("John")
    stage.step = step

    expect:
    stage.run() == "Joe"
  }

  def "use global GroovySpy"() {
    given:
    GroovySpy(Step, global: true) {
      getName() >> "Joe"
    }
    Step.staticMethod() >> "stubbed"
    def stage = new Stage("John")

    expect:
    Step.staticMethod() == "stubbed"
    stage.run() == "Joe"
  }

  def "use global GroovyMock"() {
    given:
    GroovyMock(Step, global: true)
    new Step(*_) >> Mock(Step) {
      getName() >> "Joe"
    }
    Step.staticMethod() >> "stubbed"
    def stage = new Stage("John")

    expect:
    Step.staticMethod() == "stubbed"
    stage.run() == "Joe"
  }

}
```

P.S.: I think, you probably read the Spock manual, but just in case: If your `GroovyMock/Stub/Spy` target is implemented in a language other than Groovy such as Java or Kotlin, this will not work because then `Groovy*` will behave like a regular Spock mock/stub/spy.

---

**Update:** I just created [Spock issue #1159](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1159), first of all in order to get this behaviour documented and covered by tests, but in order to get it also changed, if it was not intended like this.

Comment: Thanks, this was extremely detailed and looks to have solved the crux of my issue. I was going to file a defect as well, but awesome to see you did that already. One last question that maybe you can assist with as well, when trying to check the `1 * testMock.getName()` I get one of two errors:
`def testMock = GroovyMock(TestStep, global: true)` Declaring this way and doing the check errors out with `Too few invocations`.
`def testMock = new TestStep(*_) >> Mock(TestStep) {` Declaring this way returns an error that right shift cannot be performed on null object.
Any insight is appreciated

Comment: I got this working actually, had to adjust the check to happen in the root level spy (weird that adding the `1 * ` check added the override. Here's the final function.  

```
  void "test"() {
    setup:
    GroovySpy(TestStep, global: true) {
      1 * getName() >> "Joe"
    }
    when:
    TestStage stage = new TestStage("Susan")
    def result = stage.run()
    then:
    result == "Joe"
  }
```